# Android Studio Electric Eel new error when deploying: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries

Tags: android, macos

I have been working on a project in Android Studio, and was previously not having any issues deploying/debugging. I am getting an error when trying to deploy/debug my package on both the emulator and a physical device.

After updating to Electric Eel, I am getting the following when trying to deploy the package to the emulator:

> INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries

I have tried uninstalling the emulator, deleting all AVDs, reinstalling the emulator, and I can't get past this error. I've also tried setting the abifilter in the build.gradle to include all architectures.

I am using M1 silicone mac with latest MacOS, latest Android Studio, latest components. The emulators are all ARM based (can't run the x86_64 ones - they don't launch, and I've never needed them).

Answer (score 0):

After numerous hours of troubleshooting, I figured out it was a single line in my gradle build file which was the issue:

```
implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

Replaced it with the following:

```
api group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

and now is fixed.

I must've added the line a few weeks ago and not tested, and when I reopened my project couldn't remember the last change I had made.